# Way to debug CORS errors

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, firefox, cors

Every once in a while I have to debug cross-origin resource sharing related problems during web-development.

To my testing, Chrome and Firefox give virtually no information when they cancel a request due to a CORS violation. Usually debugging involes checking the all the headers against specs, reading the CORS standard etc. It is a really cumbersome process.

Isn't there a way to tell any Browser that it should be more verbose about **why** it canceled a specific request?

For example, I rather have more verbose debug messages like `Request canceled due to missing X-Requested-With field in received Access-Control-Allow-Headers field` or `Request canceled because supplied Origin: and received Access-Control-Allow-Origin: fields mismatch`.

Comment: Almost two years later and Firefox still gives a generic "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at {URL}. (Reason: CORS request failed)"

Comment: @Dyna, Isn't it written at `<Ctrl><Shift><I>`?

Comment: @Pacerier nowadays yes, chrome did a good job displaying the errors at the console. At the time I asked the questions there were only very generic error messages, that did not help at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which version of Chrome are you using? The latest versions have become much better at reporting CORS issues. For example, I am using Chrome version "32.0.1700.14 beta", and when I visit [this page](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&client_headers=X-Foo:%201&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=local), I get the following error in my console:

```
Request header field X-Foo is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

This information is only available from the console, and cannot be programmatically accessed. Hopefully more browsers will follow suit. Note that if your request fails for some other, non-CORS reason, you may still see unhelpful error messages.

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox doesn't generate an error on that page.

Answer (score 10):

While browsers still aren't very helpful here, I recently built a webpage that can tell you exactly what's going on, and why, and exactly how to fix it. It's effectively an interactive self-explaining flowchart of the whole CORS system.

If you're stuck trying to debug your CORS setup, try it out: https://httptoolkit.com/will-it-cors/