# Issues consuming WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui, iis-7

Using `VS2010`, we deployed a `WCF service` to our remote server in the same network. We use `IIS 7`. This project is called `WcfService`.

Opening my browser locally and entering the `http://RemoteServer/Service1.svc/GetSales?Band=Last` will return correct `json` data. So the project works and it's not a firewall issue.

If I set my report to the URL above, the graphs in the report *will not* be displayed.

During debug of `WcfService`, if I set the report to the local url (`http://localhost:1023/Service1.svc/GetSales?Band=Last`) then the graphs in the report are shown correctly.

What can the issue be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you "testing" RemoteServer/Service1.svc/GetSales?Band=Last when you return JSON? Your problem might be CORS related.  You can try this [Enable CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7)

You can debug this in Chrome [Debug CORS in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032037/way-to-debug-cors-errors)

Comment: I'm assuming that it's working because I call the method in a browser, and the "remote version" returns exactly the same string as the "local version". I use the "local version" in my report and all the graphs are being displayed correctly.

Comment: Seeing the Chrome DevTools I just noticed it's a CORS related issue.

Comment: This SO link worked. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760982/could-not-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-my-wcf-library-project